# words need to be more appart from eachother and more in the middle of the screen..

Tags: html, css

This might seem rather easy to solve, but I couldn't find an answer on stackoverflow nor anywhere on the internet to solve my little problem..

I need these http://prntscr.com/a0y8jm words to be more in the middle of the screen, and I need to be able to put the words more appart from eachother, I first used Padding, but I don't really think that works out so well, and the words aren't responding on padding anymore eighter (because I made the layout different)

anyone got any tips on how to make this work, and if you have some tips for the other parts of my code, those are always welcome too. I am not in programming that long yet, so I could use all the information I can get :)

This is my code,

```css
body, html {
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: georgia, "Comic Sans MS";
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

header {
  height: 5%;
  border-bottom: thick solid grey;
}

.img {
  width: 25%;
  height: 30%;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  float: left;
}
.antwoord {
  float: left;
  width: 95%;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-width: 4px;
}

.move1 {

}
.move2 {
margin-top: 12.5%
}
.move4 {
margin-top: 19%
}
.move5 {
margin-top: 33.5%
}
.move6 {
margin-top: 20.8%
}
.move7 {
margin-top: 37.5%
}

.word, .word .tekst, .word p {
  display: inline;
}
.my-row{
  clear: both;
}
.answers .word, .answers .word2{
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100px;
}

footer {
    border-top: thick solid grey;
    height: 5%;
    display : table-row;
    vertical-align : bottom;

}

.points {
    float: right;
}
.container {
  height:100%;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  display : table;
}
.igen {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.sprint {
  float: right;
}
.copyright {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Words</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <script>

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<header>
 <span class="fa fa-refresh" style="font-size:25px;"></span><span class="igen">&nbsp;igen</span>
 <span class="points"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:24px"></i>Rigtige:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>Forkerte: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 0</span>
</header>

<div class="container">


      <div class="img" id="img1">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje1"><center><img src="img/cat.jpg" alt="cat" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move1"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord1"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img2">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje1"><center><img src="img/beak.jpg" alt="beak" width="50%;"></div>
            <div class="move2"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord2"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img3">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje3"><center><img src="img/spoon.jpg" alt="spoon" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move3"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord3"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img4">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje4"><center><img src="img/milk.jpg" alt="milk" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move4"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord4"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img5">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje5"><center><img src="img/egg.jpg" alt="egg" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move5"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord5"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img6">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje6"><center><img src="img/thee.jpg" alt="tea" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move6"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord6"></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="img" id="img7">
          <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje7"><center><img src="img/meel.jpg" alt="meel" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move7"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord7"></div></div>
          </div>
          <div class="img" id="img8">
              <div class="plaatje" id="plaatje8"><center><img src="img/passport.jpg" alt="passport" width="50%;"></div>
          <div class="move8"><div class="antwoord" id="antwoord8"></div></div>
          </div>

          <div class="answers">
            <div class="my-row"> 
              <div class="word" id="word1">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst1"> <p>Cat</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word" id="word2">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst2"> <p>spoon</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word" id="word3">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst3"> <p>meal</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word" id="word4">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst4"> <p>passport</p> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
              <div class="word2" id="word5">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst5"> <p>egg</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word2" id="word6">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst6"> <p>beak</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word2" id="word7">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst7"> <p>tea</p> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="word2" id="word8">
                <div class="tekst" id="tekst8"> <p>milk</p> </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
<footer>
<img class="dansk" id="dansk" src="img/dansk2.jpg" alt="dansk" />
<img class="sprint" id="sprint" src="img/sprint2.png" alt="sprint" />
<center><span class="copyright"> &copy;2013 laerdansk / FC-Sprint&sup2; Leerbedrijf bronnen </span></center>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is *supposed* to look like?

Comment: Also `<center>` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: use margin instead padding

Comment: @Paulie_D how do you mean, can't it be used in todays browsers anymore? (english isn't my native language) 

And thanks @Chris!

Comment: @Paulie_D it is sort of supposed to look like this http://prntscr.com/a0ys0y .. wich I just made with the margin, but then the words need to be right.
If you can understand what I mean :s

Comment: Yes, `center` is now an invalid element and browser might stop accepting it in the future.

Comment: Try adding `margin: 0 auto;` to the container class.

Comment: owh! thanks for the update! Do you maybe know what I can use to make the pictures go into the center as a replacement? @Paulie_D

Comment: To be honest I'd probably need to tear down the whole structure and rethink it.

Comment: @cdslijngard for how far I've seen, that doesn't do anything, I currently already have the words like this http://prntscr.com/a0yy6i as I stated in a comment before, and I'm stuck again that the words aren't equal to eachother, that, for an example, **egg** isn't directly beneath **cat** and I need that to be so..

Comment: oh, alright, thanks anyway @Paulie_D

Comment: @Paulie_D I could easly center the images by using **margin-left and margin-right** and then those with diffrent precentages, it works quite nicely. Thanks for updating me about the <center> tag :)